Shor’s / qiskit.circuit.exceptions.CircuitError: 'duplicate qubit arguments'
All code for Quantum Realiazition Shor's algoritm
P.S. I hope all operation almost correct.
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from math import pi

Pcurve = 4294967311
Acurve = 0
Bcurve = 7
Gx, Gy = 2502914690, 3608000288  
num_qubits = 32

def apply_kqft(circuit, qubits):
    num_qubits = len(qubits)
    for j in range(num_qubits):
        circuit.h(qubits[j])
        for k in range(j + 1, num_qubits):
            angle = -pi / float(2 ** (k - j))
            circuit.cp(angle, qubits[k], qubits[j])

def apply_inverse_kqft(circuit, qubits):
    """ Apply the inverse KQFT to a register of qubits. """
    num_qubits = len(qubits)
    for j in range(num_qubits - 1, -1, -1):
        for k in range(num_qubits - 1, j, -1):
            angle = pi / float(2 ** (k - j))
            circuit.cp(angle, qubits[k], qubits[j])
        circuit.h(qubits[j])

def quantum_subtraction(circuit, qr_a, qr_b, qr_result, qr_borrow):
    """Subtracts qr_b from qr_a and stores the result in qr_result."""
    num_qubits = len(qr_a)
    for i in range(num_qubits):
        circuit.cx(qr_b[i], qr_a[i])
        circuit.ccx(qr_borrow[i], qr_a[i], qr_b[i])

def controlled_subtraction(circuit, qr_a, qr_b, qr_control):
    num_qubits = len(qr_a)
    for i in range(num_qubits):
        # Используем логику проверки без дополнительных кубитов
        if qr_control == qr_a[i] or qr_control == qr_b[i]:
            # Пропустим дублирование в этом случае
            continue
        circuit.ccx(qr_control, qr_b[i], qr_a[i])

def quantum_division(circuit, qr_dividend, qr_divisor, qr_quotient, qr_remainder, qr_control):
    num_qubits = len(qr_dividend)
    for i in range(num_qubits):
        circuit.cx(qr_dividend[i], qr_remainder[i])

    for i in range(num_qubits - 1, -1, -1):
        controlled_subtraction(circuit, qr_remainder, qr_divisor, qr_control)
        circuit.cx(qr_remainder[num_qubits - 1], qr_quotient[i])
        controlled_subtraction(circuit, qr_remainder, qr_divisor, qr_control)

def quantum_multiplication(circuit, qr_a, qr_b, qr_product):
    """Multiplies qr_a and qr_b storing the result in qr_product."""
    num_qubits = len(qr_a)
    qr_temp = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, 'temp')
    circuit.add_register(qr_temp)
    for i in range(num_qubits):
        for j in range(num_qubits):
            circuit.ccx(qr_a[i], qr_b[j], qr_temp[j])
            circuit.cx(qr_temp[j], qr_product[i + j])
            circuit.ccx(qr_a[i], qr_b[j], qr_temp[j])

def elliptic_curve_addition(circuit, qr_p, qr_q, qr_result, qr_borrow, qr_control):
    """ Performs elliptic curve addition on the quantum circuit. """
    num_qubits = len(qr_p) // 2
    qr_x1, qr_y1 = qr_p[:num_qubits], qr_p[num_qubits:]
    qr_x2, qr_y2 = qr_q[:num_qubits], qr_q[num_qubits:]
    qr_slope = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, 'slope')
    circuit.add_register(qr_slope)
    quantum_subtraction(circuit, qr_y2, qr_y1, qr_slope, qr_borrow)
    quantum_subtraction(circuit, qr_x2, qr_x1, qr_result, qr_borrow)
    quantum_division(circuit, qr_slope, qr_result, qr_slope, qr_result, qr_control)
    quantum_multiplication(circuit, qr_slope, qr_result, qr_slope)

def create_modular_inversion_circuit(num_qubits):
    qr_a = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, 'a')
    qr_n = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, 'n')
    qr_inv = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, 'inv')
    qr_carry = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, 'carry')
    qr_control = QuantumRegister(1, 'control')
    qr_borrow = QuantumRegister(num_qubits, 'borrow')
    cr = ClassicalRegister(num_qubits, 'output')
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr_a, qr_n, qr_inv, qr_carry, qr_control, qr_borrow, cr)

    for i in range(num_qubits):
        circuit.h(qr_a[i])
        circuit.h(qr_n[i])

    elliptic_curve_addition(circuit, qr_a, qr_n, qr_inv, qr_borrow, qr_control[0])
    apply_kqft(circuit, qr_inv)
    apply_inverse_kqft(circuit, qr_inv)
    circuit.measure(qr_inv, cr)
    return circuit

circuit = create_modular_inversion_circuit(num_qubits)
print(circuit.draw())
simulator = AerSimulator()
job = simulator.run(circuit)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts()
print("Measurement results:", counts)
plot_histogram(counts)


Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. What is your question?

Good afternoon! Thanks! The problem with the double use of the qubit is deduced. Probably in ccx. Can you help with setting up the code? How can I fix this error?

it looks like qr_a[i] and qr_b[i] in controlled_subtraction() could be the same, thus duplicated?
